# In SQL Count number of distinct values corresponding to a same Id and DISPLAY in a same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck on a SQL query. I have results as below in a table and have to display the final result in a report as below:

```
id  Question
-------------
13  ABC
13  ABC
13  QWE
13  ABC
13  QWE
13  ABC
```

Expected result:

```
id   Result
--------------------
13   4 ABC, 2 QWE
```

Can somebody please help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Which version of sql server, 2016 or 2017 added new functions to make that easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires pre-aggregation and string aggregation.

```
with t as (
      select id, question, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by id
     )
select i.id,
       stuff( (select ', ' + convert(varchar(255), cnt) + ' ' + question
               from t t2
               where t2.id = i.id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as result
from (select distinct id from t) i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--testdata-begin
if not object_id(N'Tempdb..#T') is null
    drop table #T
Go
Create table #T([id] int,[Question] nvarchar(23))
Insert #T
select 13,N'ABC' union all
select 13,N'ABC' union all
select 13,N'QWE' union all
select 13,N'ABC' union all
select 13,N'QWE' union all
select 13,N'ABC'
Go
--testdata-end
WITH cte AS  (
Select id,Question,COUNT(1) AS num from #T GROUP BY id,Question
)
SELECT id,
       STUFF(
       (
           SELECT ',' + RTRIM(b.num) + ' ' + b.Question
           FROM cte b
           WHERE a.id = b.id
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ),
       1,
       1,
       ''
            ) AS Result
FROM cte a
GROUP BY id;
```